# Match the regex when i have one or more same character behind a point

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regex which will do that :

I have for example :

```
4.00
52.0000
8544.00000
455.00045
```

I only want to match numbers who got only zeros (one or more than one) behind the dot.  So i am trying to have this result :

```
4
52
8544
455.00045
```

I have something like that currently `\.[0]+0` but it's not sufficient

Thanks for answers

Comment: Yes, that's to show for the example that the regex need to let ```455.00045``` as before

Comment: Are these numbers separate strings, or are they part of a longer string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for your matches:

```sh
^\d+(?:(?=\.0+$)|\.\d+$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nami8N/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits at the start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?=\.0+$)`: Lookahead to assert that we match dot and 1+ zeroes till end
  - `|`: OR
  - `\.\d+$`: Match a dot followed by 1+ digits
- `)`: End non-capture group

Answer (score 2):

So you want to remove `\.0+$`?

```
sed 's/\.00*$//'
```